# Error: illegal cast: from 'int' to 'union'

Tags: c++, data-structures, casting, unions

I'm getting the error, `illegal cast: from 'int' to 'FIELDS'` while initializing the structure variables here:-

```
SOCKET_LOG_DATA socket_log_data() : fields(0), socket_number(0) {}
```

How should I resolve it?

```
typedef PACKED struct PACKED_SUFFIX
{
      UINT16 loss_reason : 1;
      UINT16 unused : 15;
} LOSS_REASON;

typedef union PACKED_SUFFIX
{
      LOSS_REASON loss;
      UINT16 all_fields;
} FIELDS;

typedef PACKED struct PACKED_SUFFIX SOCKET_LOG_DATA
{
      FIELDS fields;
      UINT16 socket_number;

      // As per @Dietrich's & @crashmstrcomments:-
      SOCKET_LOG_DATA() : fields{{0, 0}}, socket_number(0) {}
} SOCKET_LOG_DATA;
```

Gave a lot many errors:-

```
".filename.h", line 183: error (dplus:1207): syntax error near }
".filename.h", line 183: error (dplus:1463): type expected in arg-declaration-clause
".filename.h", line 183: error (dplus:1263): identifier socket_number already declared
".filename.h", line 183: error (dplus:1376): function int socket_number(void) is not a member of class $incomplete SOCKET_LOG_DATA
".filename.h", line 183: error (dplus:1247): syntax error after fields, expecting (
".filename.h", line 183: error (dplus:1404): mem initializers only allowed for constructors
".filename.h", line 183: error (dplus:1247): syntax error after 0, expecting ;
```

Then I retained `socket_log_data()` constructor by changing the line to

```
SOCKET_LOG_DATA socket_log_data() : fields{{0, 0}}, socket_number(0) {}
```

, and received following errors:-

```
".filename.h", line 183: error (dplus:1272): member $incomplete SOCKET_LOG_DATA::fields used outside non-static member function
".filename.h", line 183: error (dplus:1125): int constant expected
".filename.h", line 183: error (dplus:1536): bitfields must be integral type
".filename.h", line 183: error (dplus:1247): syntax error after fields, expecting ;
".filename.h", line 183: error (dplus:1436): syntax error - declarator expected after }
".filename.h", line 183: error (dplus:1461): type expected for socket_number
".filename.h", line 183: error (dplus:1247): syntax error after ), expecting ;
".filename.h", line 186: error (dplus:1461): type expected for SOCKET_LOG_DATA
```

Comment: What is `fields(0)` supposed to do?

Comment: I don't think `SOCKET_LOG_DATA socket_log_data()` is right, the constructor should just be `SOCKET_LOG_DATA() : ...`?

Comment: @crashmstr: did just that. got errors. please see above.

Comment: @StenSoft: `fields(0)` essentially intended to by default set all its values to zero.

Comment: Union has only one value (which can be accessed via multiple ways). That's the difference between union and struct. You can use default initializer `{}` to zero-initialize the whole union.

Comment: @SaiKamat no, you *did not* do that, you had `SOCKET_LOG_DATA : ...` which is *very* different from `SOCKET_LOG_DATA() : ...`. A constructor must not declare a return type and must exactly match the name of the class or struct.

Comment: @crashmstr: sorry about that, I've changed it to SOCKET_LOG_DATA() : .... But still got the above errors.

Comment: @SaiKamat not sure, it looks like it if pointing to the `fields{{0, 0}}`. Try taking that out and initializing in the body of the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related query

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35549540/identifier-int-not-a-direct-member-of-struct-socket-log-data/35555783#35555783](http://here)

I fixed this with proper constructor initialization and member variable placement as follows:-

```
typedef struct fields
{
    UINT16 loss_reason : 1;
    UINT16 unused : 15;
} FIELDS;

typedef union fields_union
{
    UINT16 all_fields;
    FIELDS ref_fields;
    fields_union() : all_fields(0), ref_fields() {}
} FIELDS_UNION;

typedef struct socket_log_data
{
    FIELDS_UNION ref_fields_union;
    UINT16 socket_number;
    socket_log_data() : socket_number(0), ref_fields_union() {}
} SOCKET_LOG_DATA;
```

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 5):

You are initializing a `union` with a single `int`:

```
: fields(0)
```

You can initialize the first union member like this, instead:

```
: fields{{0, 0}}
```

There's also something fishy with the constructor:

```
SOCKET_LOG_DATA socket_log_data() ...
```

Ordinarily, it would just be:

```
SOCKET_LOG_DATA() ...
```

Comment: It should be `SOCKET_LOG_DATA() : fields{{0, 0}}, socket_number(0) {}`. You must include the `()` to show that it is a function.

Comment: @RobK: The `...` means that something has been omitted.

Comment: My comment was directed at Sai Kamat, as an elaboration on your answer.