# illegal cast: from struct 'socket_log_data' to 'unsigned int' data

Tags: c++, struct, casting, parameter-passing, typecasting-operator

I've a function `logEthernetConnection()` which takes an integer as a parameter.
However, requirement suggests I pass a struct to it.
I've typecasted the struct while passing, yet I obtain the error as mentioned in the title:-

```
 error (dplus:1061): illegal cast: from 'socket_log_data' to 'unsigned int'
```

Here's the code snippet:-

```
typedef struct fields
{
    UINT16 loss_reason : 1;
    UINT16 unused : 15;
} FIELDS;

typedef union fields_union
{
    UINT16 all_fields;
    FIELDS ref_fields;
    fields_union() : all_fields(0), ref_fields() {}
} FIELDS_UNION;

typedef struct socket_log_data
{
    FIELDS_UNION ref_fields_union;
    UINT16 socket_number;
    socket_log_data() : socket_number(0), ref_fields_union() {}
} SOCKET_LOG_DATA;

int logEthernetConnection(UINT32 data)
{
    return data;
}
void main()
{
    UINT32 data = logEthernetConnection((UINT32)socket_log_data);
    getchar();
}
```

How should I fix this?

Related query posted here:-
[Error: illegal cast: from 'int' to 'union'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35485404/error-illegal-cast-from-int-to-union/35555859#35555859)

Comment: You should drop the `typedef`s from all the structs. That's an archaic usage held-over from C and it should not be used in C++.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass a struct to a function which expects an integer! What would the function do with that (suppose, you manage to cast it through dirty hackery).

How would the function handle it?

Answer (score -1):

The structure you are trying to cast is bigger in size than UINT32. Moreover, you can not cast like this a structure to an int (no matter the size). I guess what you want to do is to cast a UINT16 member of the structure socket_log_data like :

```
 void main()
{
    socket_log_data my_var_struct;
    // Fill the my_var_struct

    UINT32 data = logEthernetConnection( (UINT32) my_var_struct.socket_number);

    getchar();
}
```

Hope this help !